# How to retrieve a variable given from onActivityResult

Tags: java, android

I need to call for a variable that is defined inside `onActivityResult()`, and retrieve it's value inside my main method. Here is my code

```
@Override
protected void onStart() {
    final int questionsToAsk = 5;
    super.onStart();
    boolean[] questionsDone;
    final Intent nextLevelScreen = getIntent();
    final int[] questionsOrder = nextLevelScreen.getIntArrayExtra("questionsOrder");
    final int[] currentIterator = {nextLevelScreen.getIntExtra("currIterator", 0)};
    final int[] currentQuest = {questionsOrder[currentIterator[0]]};
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_nextlevel_screen);
    questionsDone = nextLevelScreen.getBooleanArrayExtra("questionsDONE");
    ProgressBar barOfProgress = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.barToShowProgress);
    barOfProgress.setMax(questionsToAsk);
    barOfProgress.setProgress(currentIterator[0]);
    ImageButton btnToNextQuestion = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.buttonToNextQuestion);
    final boolean[] finalQuestionsDone = questionsDone;
    if (currentIterator[0] > questionsToAsk - 1) {
        btnToNextQuestion.setImageResource(R.drawable.botaoproximatela);
    } else {
        btnToNextQuestion.setImageResource(R.drawable.botaoproximonivel);
    }
    btnToNextQuestion.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            if (currentIterator[0] > questionsToAsk - 1) {
                System.out.println("Game Over");
                boolean[] correctAnswers = new boolean[5];
                Intent answersIntent = getIntent();
                for (int n = 0; n<5; n++) {
                    int currQuest = currentQuest[0];
                    switch (currQuest) {
                        case 0:
                            correctAnswers[n] = answersIntent.getBooleanExtra("isOneCorrect", false);
                            break;
                        case 1:
                            correctAnswers[n] = answersIntent.getBooleanExtra("isTwoCorrect", false);
                            break;
                        case 2:
                            correctAnswers[n] = answersIntent.getBooleanExtra("isThreeCorrect", false);
                            break;
                        case 3:
                            correctAnswers[n] = answersIntent.getBooleanExtra("isFourCorrect", false);
                            break;
                        case 4:
                            correctAnswers[n] = answersIntent.getBooleanExtra("isFiveCorrect", false);
                            break;
                        case 5:
                            correctAnswers[n] = answersIntent.getBooleanExtra("isSixCorrect", false);
                            break;
                        case 6:
                            correctAnswers[n] = answersIntent.getBooleanExtra("isSevenCorrect", false);
                            break;
                        case 7:
                            correctAnswers[n] = answersIntent.getBooleanExtra("isEightCorrect", false);
                            break;
                        case 8:
                            correctAnswers[n] = answersIntent.getBooleanExtra("isNineCorrect", false);
                            break;
                        case 9:
                            correctAnswers[n] = answersIntent.getBooleanExtra("isTenCorrect", false);
                            break;
                    }
                }
                System.out.println(Arrays.toString(correctAnswers));
                setContentView(R.layout.activity_endgame_screen);
                ImageButton returnbtn = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btnToReturn);
                returnbtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        finish();
                    }
                });
            } else {
                Intent nextQuestionToAsk = null;
                switch (questionsOrder[currentIterator[0]]) {
                    case 0:
                        nextQuestionToAsk = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Quest1.class);
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        nextQuestionToAsk = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Quest2.class);
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        nextQuestionToAsk = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Quest3.class);
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        nextQuestionToAsk = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Quest4.class);
                        break;
                    case 4:
                        nextQuestionToAsk = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Quest5.class);
                        break;
                    case 5:
                        nextQuestionToAsk = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Quest6.class);
                        break;
                    case 6:
                        nextQuestionToAsk = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Quest7.class);
                        break;
                    case 7:
                        nextQuestionToAsk = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Quest8.class);
                        break;
                    case 8:
                        nextQuestionToAsk = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Quest9.class);
                        break;
                    case 9:
                        nextQuestionToAsk = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Quest10.class);
                        break;
                    default:
                        System.out.println("Out of bounds");
                        break;
                }
                final Intent finalNextQuestionToAsk = nextQuestionToAsk;
                if (finalNextQuestionToAsk != null) {
                    currentIterator[0]++;
                    System.out.println("curr It" + currentIterator[0]);
                    nextLevelScreen.putExtra("currIterator", currentIterator[0]);
                    finalQuestionsDone[questionsOrder[currentIterator[0] - 1]] = true;
                    nextLevelScreen.putExtra("questionsDONE", finalQuestionsDone);
                    startActivityForResult(finalNextQuestionToAsk, currentQuest[0]);
                }

            }
        }
    });
}
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    Intent answersIntent = getIntent();
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    System.out.println("Received Result");
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
    switch (requestCode){
        case 0:
            final boolean oneIsCorrect = data.getBooleanExtra("oneIsCorrect", false);
            if (oneIsCorrect) {
                System.out.println("Correct");
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Correto :)", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                answersIntent.putExtra("isOneCorrect", true);
            } else {
                System.out.println("Wrong");
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Errado", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            break;
        case 1:
            final boolean twoIsCorrect = data.getBooleanExtra("twoIsCorrect", false);
            if (twoIsCorrect) {
                System.out.println("Correct");
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Correto :)", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                answersIntent.putExtra("isTwoCorrect", true);
            } else {
                System.out.println("Wrong");
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Errado", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            break;
        case 2:
            final boolean threeIsCorrect = data.getBooleanExtra("threeIsCorrect", false);
            if (threeIsCorrect) {
                System.out.println("Correct");
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Correto :)", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                answersIntent.putExtra("isThreeCorrect", true);
            } else {
                System.out.println("Wrong");
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Errado", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            break;
        case 3:
            final boolean fourIsCorrect = data.getBooleanExtra("fourIsCorrect", false);
            if (fourIsCorrect) {
                System.out.println("Correct");
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Correto :)", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                answersIntent.putExtra("isFourCorrect", true);
            } else {
                System.out.println("Wrong");
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Errado", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            break;
        case 4:
            final boolean fiveIsCorrect = data.getBooleanExtra("fiveIsCorrect", false);
            if (fiveIsCorrect) {
                System.out.println("Correct");
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Correto :)", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                answersIntent.putExtra("isFiveCorrect", true);
            } else {
                System.out.println("Wrong");
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Errado", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            break;
        case 5:
            final boolean sixIsCorrect = data.getBooleanExtra("sixIsCorrect", false);
            if (sixIsCorrect) {
                System.out.println("Correct");
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Correto :)", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                answersIntent.putExtra("isSixCorrect", true);
            } else {
                System.out.println("Wrong");
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Errado", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            break;
        case 6:
            final boolean sevenIsCorrect = data.getBooleanExtra("sevenIsCorrect", false);
            if (sevenIsCorrect) {
                System.out.println("Correct");
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Correto :)", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                answersIntent.putExtra("isSevenCorrect", true);
            } else {
                System.out.println("Wrong");
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Errado", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            break;
        case 7:
            final boolean eightIsCorrect = data.getBooleanExtra("eightIsCorrect", false);
            if (eightIsCorrect) {
                System.out.println("Correct");
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Correto :)", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                answersIntent.putExtra("isEightCorrect", true);
            } else {
                System.out.println("Wrong");
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Errado", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            break;
        case 8:
            final boolean nineIsCorrect = data.getBooleanExtra("nineIsCorrect", false);
            if (nineIsCorrect) {
                System.out.println("Correct");
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Correto :)", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                answersIntent.putExtra("isNineCorrect", true);
            } else {
                System.out.println("Wrong");
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Errado", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            break;
        case 9:
            final boolean tenIsCorrect = data.getBooleanExtra("tenIsCorrect", false);
            if (tenIsCorrect) {
                System.out.println("Correct");
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Correto :)", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                answersIntent.putExtra("isTenCorrect", true);
            } else {
                System.out.println("Wrong");
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Errado", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            break;
        default:
            System.out.println("OUTOFBOUNDS_code=" + requestCode);
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

I've tried to use an Intent to store all the values, but when I call them with `System.out.println(Arrays.toString(correctAnswers));`, after setting the values, I get a full false array.
What is wrong? Thanks in advance

Comment: One cannot call a variable. About which variable are you talking?

Answer (score 0):

`onActivityResult` is called when you return from another activity with a result Intent.
If you need to set variables or execute methods when this happens, do it from inside `onActivityResult`.

```
  oncreate {
      ...
  }

  public void doWhatYouNeedHere() {
      ...
  }

  protected void onActivityResult() {
      ...
      doWhatYouNeedHere()
      ...
  }
```

Or perhaps you can set a listener.

Comment: Please use code format option if you add code to your answer. Code will be automatically formated if you intend the line by some leading spaces.